# Using pseudonym in WHERE clause in MYSQL query

Tags: mysql

Please don't bite me for this, but I'm new to mysql and I have some problem with using pseudonym in WHERE clause. I thought that it is possible to use pseudonym for aggregate function, defined in the select statement.
Here is my query

```
SELECT a.name, s.name, COUNT(e.id) as total FROM athletes a 
INNER JOIN sports s on s.id = a.sport_id 
INNER JOIN events e on s.id = e.sport_id 
WHERE total >=2 GROUP BY a.name
```

But, I catch an error "Unknown column total in WHERE clause".
Could anyone tell me if it is right to do query like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use alias in the where clause. You need to use that in `having`

```
SELECT 
a.name, 
s.name, 
COUNT(e.id) as total FROM athletes a 
INNER JOIN sports s on s.id = a.sport_id 
INNER JOIN events e on s.id = e.sport_id  
GROUP BY a.name having total >=2
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of WHERE total >=2 you can use HAVING (total >= 2 )

HAVING:

```
SELECT a.name, s.name, COUNT(e.id) as total 
FROM athletes a 
INNER JOIN sports s on s.id = a.sport_id 
INNER JOIN events e on s.id = e.sport_id  
GROUP BY a.name, s.name 
HAVING (total >= 2 );
```

Comment: This works only with HAVING function. Statement 
`WHERE COUNT(e.id) >=2`  also throw an error "Invalid use of group fucntion"

Comment: @volodymyr3131 tested it and indeed an error occured. So removed the bad code. Thanks!

Comment: @volodymyr3131 This is because `HAVING` works on an intermediate result set after grouping, while `WHERE` works on the table data itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can not use an column alias in where clause. you have to use the expression `COUNT(e.id)` in where clasue or you can use the alias in a having clause:

```
SELECT a.name, s.name, COUNT(e.id) as total FROM athletes a INNER JOIN sports s on s.id = a.sport_id INNER JOIN events e on s.id = e.sport_id WHERE COUNT(e.id)>=2 GROUP BY a.name
```

or

```
SELECT a.name, s.name, COUNT(e.id) as total FROM athletes a INNER JOIN sports s on s.id = a.sport_id INNER JOIN events e on s.id = e.sport_id having total>=2 GROUP BY a.name
```